# WPF Dynamic Grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to build a grid dynamically with column span.

Considering the maximum columns as 12 like Bootstrap...

if there are 3 elements:
  1 - Image Size of 4 columns.
  2 - image Size of 8 columns.
  3 - Label Size of 12 columns.

```
+------------+-----------+  
|            |           |  
|    0,0     |    0,1    |  
|            |           |  
+------------+-----------+  
|            |           |  
|    1,0     |           |  
|            |           |  
+------------------------+
```

```cs
var NumberOfColumns = 12.0 / layoutElements.Min(x => x.Colsize);
    var NumberOfRows = Math.Ceiling(layoutElements.Sum(x => x.Colsize) / 12.0);

    for (int ColNo = 0; ColNo < NumberOfColumns; ColNo++) {
        ColumnDefinition gridColo = new ColumnDefinition();
        cardGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColo);
    }

    for (int RowNo = 0; RowNo < NumberOfRows; RowNo++) {
        RowDefinition gridRow = new RowDefinition();
        cardGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow);
    }

    Label lblTestObject3 = new Label();
    lblTestObject3.Content = "Test Label .........";
    Grid.SetRow(lblTestObject3, 3);
    Grid.SetColumn(lblTestObject3, 3);
    cardGrid.Children.Add(lblTestObject3);

    Label lblTestObject4 = new Label();
    lblTestObject4.Content = "Test Label------- ";
    Grid.SetRow(lblTestObject4, 1);
    Grid.SetColumn(lblTestObject4, 3);
    cardGrid.Children.Add(lblTestObject4);
```

I'm testing with labels control, but the elements are getting overridden, moreover I need to merge columns.

Comment: I can help with this, can you add a picture of what you want to happen as the size changes?